# Proguard - Android - Exception while processing task java.io.IOException

Tags: android, proguard

I am getting the following error using proguard in android

```
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write
    [/Users/test/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/BibleSociety/debug/0.jar]
(Can't read
    [/Users/test/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/core-1.0.0.aar/a934e1d2a2dbe62bd324c349a93ef4b3/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
(Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v4/c/c$a$a.class ==
    classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy.class]))
  :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForcietyDebug FAILED
```

Below is the complete build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'         

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion project.ext.buildToolsVersion
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
         manifestPlaceholders.screenOrientation = "portrait";
         minSdkVersion project.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion project.ext.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true

        //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }                       
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }    
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    flavorDimensions "api"
    productFlavors {                    
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    //library for ipay88 payment
    implementation files('libs/ipay_hosted_standard_sdk_20180514.aar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.0.4'
    implementation project(':FloatButtonLibrary')
/*    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'*/
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:' + project.ext.google_play_services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:' + project.ext.google_play_services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:' + project.ext.google_play_services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:' + project.ext.google_play_services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:' + project.ext.google_play_services

    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'    
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + project.ext.supportLibVersion
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:' + project.ext.supportLibVersion
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:' + project.ext.supportLibVersion
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:' + project.ext.supportLibVersionRecycleView

    implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.20'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
//    Video library.
    implementation 'com.twilio:video-android:2.1.1'

    implementation project(':library')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation project(':TextDrawableLibrary')

    implementation project(':richeditor')
    implementation project(':colorpickerlibrary')
    implementation project(':imageeditlibrary')
    implementation project(':sandriosCamera')
    implementation project(':colorseekbar')
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:' + project.ext.supportLibVersion

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:' + project.ext.google_play_services
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
//    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2'

    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
//    Facebook

    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)') {
        exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
    }
 //   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'
  //  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
//  Twitter Core API dependency
 //   implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
//  Twitter Compose API dependency required to Share images
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.1'
//    Scanner
//    implementation 'com.github.liltof:AndroidScannerDemo:3.2'

//    Share BottomSheet library.
//    implementation 'com.github.Kennyc1012:BottomSheet:2.4.1'

//    Youtube
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev195-1.23.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
//    Privacy checker.
    implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:PiracyChecker:1.2.5'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}

//start
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (/*(variant.buildType.debuggable)*/ variant.buildType.name.equals("release")) {
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def versionName = variant.versionName
            def versionCode = variant.versionCode
            def flavorName = variant.flavorName // e. g. free
            def buildType = variant.buildType // e. g. debug
            def variantName = variant.name // e. g. freeDebug

            def formattedDate = new Date().format('ddMMyyyy')
            def apkName = variantName + '_' + versionName + '_' + versionCode + '_' + formattedDate + '.apk';
            outputFileName = new File("", apkName)    
        }
    }
}
//end

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is proguard file

```
-keep class org.spongycastle.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.spongycastle.**
-keep class com.itextpdf.** { *; }
-keep class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.** { *; }
-dontwarn javax.xml.crypto.dsig.**

-keep class org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.**
-keep class javax.xml.crypto.dom.** { *; }
-dontwarn javax.xml.crypto.dom.**
-keep class org.apache.xml.security.utils.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.xml.security.utils.**
-keep class javax.xml.crypto.XMLStructure
-dontwarn javax.xml.crypto.XMLStructure
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep class ch.qos.** { *; }
-keep class org.slf4j.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn javax.servlet.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn android.text.StaticLayout
 -dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class ch.qos.** { *; }
```

Comment: share your progaurd file.

Comment: Hi Shane,  I have added it

Comment: share your gradle file completely. You have just shared your dependencies.

Comment: shared kindly check

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard doesn't look at your native code, so it won't automatically preserve the classes or class members that are invoked by the native code. These are entry points, which you'll have to specify explicitly.

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * { 
    native <methods>; 
}
```

In case, your application contains `enumeration` classes, you must include

```
-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * { 
    public static **[] values();
 public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); 
}
```

For serialization classes, add the following,

```
 -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable { 
     private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields; 
     private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream); 
     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream); 
     java.lang.Object writeReplace(); 
     java.lang.Object readResolve(); 
}
```

Go through [this link](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples) while applying proguard rules.

Comment: added the above 3 still the same issue

Comment: Invalidate Caches and restart, may be the issue persists with the cache files.